# How to add multiple new columns to existing csv file without mentioning the column name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add multiple columns in an existing csv. My data looks like this:

```
50451  51151  53266
 100    100    100
  1      1      1
```

where the data starting with (50...) are the columns and below them are the rows.
I have another dataset which looks similar to this:

```
50014  50013  54567
 50     100    100
```

I am using this code to change it into csv:

```
df.to_csv('fort.csv', index = False)
```

but what it does is , it replaces the old columns with new ones. Since , I have to add multiple columns , I can't use df['50014'] everytime. If you guys could suggest something , I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If the two files have the same order and amount of columns you can simply append one file to another as if it was a text file (which a csv is). You'd have to remove the duplicate column headers of course though.

Comment: The amount of columns are not similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) suffixes, to achieve this. In case there are columns with the same names the suffixes will fix the problem.

> suffixes : tuple of (str, str), default (‘_x’, ‘_y’)
>
> Suffix to apply to overlapping column names in the left and right side, respectively. To raise an exception on overlapping columns use (False, False).

---

```
r = pd.merge(df, df, right_index=True, left_index=True, suffixes=('_left', '_right'), how='outer')
print(r)
```

For simplicity, I took the same `df` again:

```
   50451  51151  53266
0    100    100    100
1      1      1      1
   50451_left  51151_left  53266_left  50451_right  51151_right  53266_right
0         100         100         100          100          100          100
1           1           1           1            1            1            1
```

Important is to use the outer join.

---

`Merge` is same as `join` except join may be handy because it is by default used on indices (indexes). They share the same code base ;).

Comment: All of the columns start with '5' , so can I use preffix instead of suffix?

Comment: Columns may start with `5` but whether the two columns are the same or not depends on remaining ciphers, right. I would take suffixes as this is provided by default.

Comment: IF I use merge @prosti , I have to mention the second dataframe everytime to merge it with the first one like df1 = pd.merge(df2) , which is not feasible for me as I have around 10,000 dataframes.

Comment: I tried it , but it is replacing the data present in my previous csv. I have created a csv with 10,000 dataframes but now I want to add 100 more into it. I don't think I'll be able to do it with this code

Comment: This looks like already answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Comment: Ok. I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry @prosti but the answer doesn't work for me as I already have large amount of data in the csv and I want to add more data which is in same format.

Comment: NO worries, ask another question specifying the right and important details in the title.